# Вывод double в java

Tags: double, java

Имею:

```
double s1 = 2.0;
double s2 = 2.3;
double s3 = 2.33,
double s4 = 2.333;
```

Требуется чтоб при выводе на экран вышли результаты:

```
s1 = 2
s2 = 2.3
s3 = 2.33
s4 = 2.333
```

Проблема в том, что надо использовать одну функцию ко все числам.

Answer (score 8):

[Formatting Numeric Print Output](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html)

Код на [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/usUKhW)

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        double s1 = 2.0; 
        double s2 = 2.3; 
        double s3 = 2.33;
        double s4 = 2.333;

        System.out.format("s1 = %.0f%n", s1);
        System.out.format("s2 = %.1f%n", s2);
        System.out.format("s3 = %.2f%n", s3);
        System.out.format("s4 = %.3f%n", s4);
        System.out.format("s1 = %.0f; s2 = %.1f; s3 = %.2f; s4 = %.3f", s1, s2, s3, s4);
    }
}
```

Comment: примите ответ, пожалуйса, если всё правильно

Answer (score 3):

Спасибо, я сам нашел уже) 10 раз заходил по первой ссылке, но не дочитывал до конца)
Вот код, который решил мою проблему.

```
import java.text.*;

public class DecimalFormatDemo {

   static public void customFormat(String pattern, double value ) {
      DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat(pattern);
      String output = myFormatter.format(value);
      System.out.println(value + "  " + pattern + "  " + output);
   }

   static public void main(String[] args) {

      customFormat("###,###.###", 123.0);
      customFormat("###,###.###", 123.120);
      customFormat("###,###.######", 123.0);
      customFormat("###,###.######, 123.123120);
   }
}
```

Результат:

```
123
123,12
123
123,12312
```